# _ as a variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I came across this function:

```
const rotatedTetro = matrix.map((_, index)=> matrix.map(col => col[index]))
```

What does the _ passed in mean?

Comment: Just a common convention for when an argument isn't being used

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing special about underscore as a variable name. It’s just a convention often used to indicate that the argument won’t be used, but it needs to be present because you need the args that follow it.

It’s a way of indicating the code is “skipping over” that argument.